# PHP delete array value

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have 2 arrays.

```
<?php
$array1 = array('id' => 1, 'email' => 'example@example.com' , 'name' => 'john' );
$array2 = array('id', 'email');
```

i am having trouble writing a code to unset the key value pair from array1 that is not from array 2.

The problem with this is unlike most examples, my array2 does not have a format of a key value pair but only key.

How do i go about removing things from array1 that is not specified in array2.

my current code is not working

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
if (array_search($key, $array2)===false) {
 unset($key);
}
}
```

Comment: Any string keys or values in your array should be enclosed in quotes so `john` should be `'john'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing it right, just that your way of `unset` is incorrect:

```
unset($key);
```

should be

```
unset($array1[$key]);
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/130035)**

Answer (score 6):

Use [`array_diff_key()`](http://php.net/array_diff_key) to leave values which are *not* in second array:

```
$array1 = array('id'=>1, 'email'=> 'email' , 'name'=>'john' );
$array2 = array('id','email');

$result = array_diff_key($array1, array_flip($array2));
```

Or, if you want to change first array:

```
$array1 = array_diff_key($array1, array_flip($array2));
```

Edit (misunderstanding)

Use [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) to leave values which *are in* second array:

```
$array1 = array_intersect_key($array1, array_flip($array2));
```

Comment: Please, leave a comment if dv - that would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe they did since the answer is not **complete**.

Comment: Well I doubt. The question isn't so bad (because it contains efforts from OP) - and code in my sample will definitely resolve the issue. In any case, just standard notice from me on dv - so I'll be able to learn my mistakes and improve my knowledge

Comment: And I edited it also - because no sense in loop if we can avoid it (and write directly to first array)

Comment: I understand why you did an arrary_diff_key, but why did you use array_flip on $array2 ?

Comment: Is it me or did you get the wrong idea of what the OP needs?

Comment: `array_flip()` is needed because your second array contains __values__, not __keys__. It's like `[0=>'id', 1=>'email']` so it's keys are `0` and `1` while for `array_diff_key()` you need to pass array with keys to get difference

Comment: I understand now, i did not know the info in $array2 was actually values and not keys.

Comment: One more thing is that as  I Can Has Cheezburger mentioned, i want to output items that are specified in $array2. So the function used should be array_intersect_key instead of array_diff_key

Answer (score 0):

You have to `unset` the element by its index (starting from 0)
For example
 `unset($array2[1]);`
will remove the 'email' element.

So in Your case it should be:
`unset($array1[$key]);`